# Elastic DSL DRF create a document and include a queryset so not all records from the model are indexed

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I have certain records in my table which I do not want to appear in my elasticsearch index at all. Is this possible to do inside the Document?

I have tried overriding get_queryset (see below) but that isn't working. Does anyone know what the best approach is here?

```
@registry.register_document
class MyDocument(Document):
    parent_id = fields.IntegerField()
    title = fields.KeywordField()

    class Django:
        # Models to include in the document
        model = MyModel

        # Fields to index for each model
        fields = [
            "id",
            ...
        ]

        def get_queryset(self):
            # Ensure we exclude certain records from being pushed to Elastic
            return super(MyDocument, self).get_queryset().exclude(exclude_me=True)

    class Index:
        # Define Elasticsearch index
        name = (
            f'{os.environ.get("CS_DEPLOYMENT", "development")}_my_document'
        )
        # Set default settings
        settings = {"number_of_shards": 1, "number_of_replicas": 0}
```